# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '81?36N'

Tags: python, valueerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/HectorVelasquez/PycharmProjects/Project 1/Project 1 python.py", line 57, in <module>
    df['log'] = df['Latitude'].apply(lambda x: convert_rad(x))
  File "/Users/HectorVelasquez/PycharmProjects/Project 1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4045, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/Users/HectorVelasquez/PycharmProjects/Project 1/Project 1 python.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    df['log'] = df['Latitude'].apply(lambda x: convert_rad(x))
  File "/Users/HectorVelasquez/PycharmProjects/Project 1/Project 1 python.py", line 7, in convert_rad
    degree = int(temp[0]) + int(temp[1][:-1])/60
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '81?36N'
```

***text file***
I don't know how to fix the error.

Latitude    Longitude   City    Province/State  Country

81?36N  16?40W  Nord    Greenland   Denmark

79?59N  85?56W  Eureka  Nunavut Canada

78?55N  11?56E  Ny-?lesund  Svalbard    Norway

78?13N  15?39E  Longyearbyen    Svalbard    Norway

***conversion function***

```
def convert_rad(lon):
    temp = lon.split('°')
    degree = int(temp[0]) + int(temp[1][:-1])/60
    direction = temp[1][-1]
    if direction=='N' or direction=='E':
        sign = 1
    elif direction=='S' or direction=='W':
        sign = -1

return degree*sign*np.pi/180
Latitude_66N = convert_rad('66°0N')
Latitude_35N_66N = convert_rad('35°0N')
Latitude_35S_35N = convert_rad('35°0S')
Latitude_35S_66S = convert_rad('66°0N')
Latitude_66S = convert_rad('66°0N')
lon = convert_rad('37°22N')
lat = convert_rad('120°42W')
```

[Image: Line 57](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOKra.png)

Comment: Without seeing the CSV content or your convert function, it's hard to say how to fix it

Comment: `int(str)` is changed from `str` to Integer, when it is able to evaluate `str` equal Integer. for example "1", "47" and so on.
Please check your data again. Latitude: `81?36N` is not able to change it. 
The latitude in your data cannot be converted to Int type as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging your problem a little and ask a minimal version of it, with enough code to reproduce it elsewhere (e.g. file and functions).  If you look at your traceback you can see the error is on the first line.  In general text is much much more useful than screenshots of text.  That being said

```
df = pd.read_csv('cities.txt', sep='\t', encoding='latin_1')
df['log'] = df['Latitude'].apply(lambda x: convert_rad(x))
```

Ignoring the backwards `'log'` and `'Latitude'`, I can see from your traceback your custom function `convert_rad` has

```
degree = int(temp[0]) + int(temp[1][:-1])/60
```

somewhere in it.  Try taking a look at your csv file for the string `81?36N`, or just using the first few lines of the file.